# Continuous nodes in Bayes net toolbox for Matlab

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, bayesian, bayesian-networks

I have a node representing a random variable whith 3314 realizations and 49 dimensions each, can it be treated as a discrete variable? Each realization is a binary vector of 49 dimensions, the other nodes are observable therefore the network training is performed with learn_params. This function transforms data as follows:

```
local_data = data(fam, :); 
if iscell(local_data)
  local_data = cell2num(local_data);
end
```

When this transformation takes place, the data lose their structure and become just an array of 162386 = (49 * 3314) so every vector of 49 dimensions cannot be seen as an embodiment of the variable, now will be 162386 realizations and the training on network node will not be correct.

I want to know if it is really possible (right?) take this variable as discrete and what training alternative I have for not modifying the data structure.

Comment: so why do you such a transformation where you lose all the data structure?

Comment: learn_params make this transformation, not me, that's why I'm asking if is rignt to treat this variable as discrete even when every realization is a binary vector of 49 dimensiones, pherhaps this is wrong. Can I attach my .m file to explain better teh problem?